# How do I download a .PNG using javascript script from a storage bucket in Supabase

Tags: javascript, supabase, supabase-database

I am trying to download a .png I have stored in my Supabase database using a javascript script. I have read the documentation and used the code snippet they provided but https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/storage-from-download#notes

What gets returned in my console is the following[image]

```js
require('dotenv').config({ path: '../.env' });
const { supabaseClient } = require('./supabaseClient.js');
bucket = '57b269d0-96b8-4dae-8c55-0e8afd8866bd';
fileName = 'OnePass/Background/services3.png';
// Download a file from the storage bucket
 supabaseClient()
  .storage
  .from(bucket)
  .download(fileName).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: yes, that's a PNG alright - in a Blob of course

Comment: Yup, so the supabase-js library did download the image for you without any issues yet it seems. What is the problem here? What are you trying to do? Are you looking to get the file URL instead of the file itself?

Comment: Hav the png download locally to my machine